# how do i fix the problem of error message USB_DEVICE_FEATURE is disabled?

Tags: c++, avr

I am currently working on an AVR32 EVK1104 board from ATMEL and I am trying to write c++ code onto the board but it is not letting me. The board was functioning but I tried to add code to it and it wiped what was on there. So now starting over I am just trying to run an example code onto the board but I always seem to get the code USB_DEVICE_FEATURE is disabled. I went to windows registry and changed the data value to 3 to make sure all ports were enabled but I still get the same error msg. Does anyone have any ideas about this ?

Comment: What API and platform is this?

Comment: Not knowing anything about this hardware, you should probably talk to the vendor.

Comment: im using AVR Studio with a JTAGEICE mkII to try to flash c++ code to the microprocessor and im using windos 7

Answer (score 1):

If you try to program the device with the JTAGICE then you will probably erase the build in bootloader.  If you then do not have valid code present the board will not appear on the USB.  Perhaps you should use he JTAG to put the bootloader back in and then use the bootloader to program the device with your code using the Atmel FLIP utility.